# Dynamic routes in Next.js app work in development mode but not in production mode (when deployed with Heroku)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server, routes

I am a beginner to React and Next.js, so apologies in advance for the long post!

I am using Next.js to create dynamic routing for my webpage for the `/course` page. My `/pages` folder has the following structure, with [slug.js] dynamically generates a set of webpages (`/course/1`, `/course/2` etc) based on a collection of markdown files:

```
/course
    [slug.js]
    index.js
config.js
download.js
index.js
```

When running the application in development mode I am able to access the dynamically generated routes (`/course/1`, `/course/2` etc) via the browser without any problems, but when I run the app in production mode and/or deploy it to Heroku, I get an error code 500 (Internal Server Error) when attempting to access these URLs, with the following logs:

```
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80,
  config: {
    url: '/coursepages/b-framework-1',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'text/markdown',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      protocol: 'http:',
      path: '/coursepages/b-framework-1',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      hostname: null,
      port: null,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/coursepages/b-framework-1'
    },
    _ended: true,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 0,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'GET /coursepages/b-framework-1 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: text/markdown\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.21.1\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/coursepages/b-framework-1',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    _currentUrl: 'http:/coursepages/b-framework-1',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
```

There are no issues with accessing the dynamically generated routes when clocking on `Link` components generated with Next.js library.

What am I missing?

Here are my `package.json` scripts:

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "nodemon server.js",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
        "lint": "next lint",
        "export": "NODE_ENV=production next build && next export -o build"
    },
    ...
}
```

Here is the custom server I have created and am using, which I store in a file called `server.js` at the root of the project:

```
require("dotenv").config()
const express = require("express")
const next = require("next")
const cors = require("cors")
const fs = require("fs")

const GenerateModel = require("./services/GenerateModel")
const { Form, Comp, Feedback } = require("./models/form")

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express()

    server.use(express.json())
    server.use(cors())

    // GET - retrive all responses
    server.get("/responses", (request, response) => {
        Form.find({})
            .then((form) => {
                response.json(form)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error)
            })
    })

    // GET - retrive a specific response by id
    server.get("/responses/:id", (request, response) => {
        Form.findById(request.params.id)
            .then((form) => {
                response.json(form)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error)
            })
    })

    // POST - create a new response
    server.post("/responses", (request, response) => {
        const body = request.body

        if (body === undefined) {
            return response.status(400).json({ error: "content missing" })
        }

        const form = new Form(body)

        form.save()
            .then((savedResponse) => {
                response.json(savedResponse)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error)
            })
    })

    // DELETE - delete a response
    server.delete("/responses/:id", (request, response, next) => {
        Form.findByIdAndRemove(request.params.id)
            .then((result) => {
                response.status(204).end()
            })
            .catch((error) => next(error))
    })

    // PUT - update a response
    server.put("/responses/:id", (request, response, next) => {
        const body = request.body

        Form.findByIdAndUpdate(request.params.id, body, { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true })
            .then((updatedResponse) => {
                response.json(updatedResponse)
            })
            .catch((error) => next(error))
    })

    // GET - retrive all comparable companies for response of id
    server.get("/responses/:id/comps", (request, response) => {
        Form.findById(request.params.id)
            .then((form) => {
                response.json(form.comps)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error)
            })
    })

    // POST - create a new comparable company
    server.post("/responses/:id/comps", (request, response, next) => {
        const body = request.body
        if (body === undefined) {
            return response.status(400).json({ error: "content missing" })
        }

        let newComp = new Comp(body)
        Form.findById(request.params.id)
            .then((existingForm) => {
                existingForm.comps.push(newComp)
                existingForm.save()
                response.json(existingForm.comps)
            })
            .catch((error) => next(error))
    })

    // DELETE - delete a comparable company
    server.delete("/responses/:id/comps/:compId", (request, response, next) => {
        Form.findById(request.params.id)
            .then((existingForm) => {
                existingForm.comps = existingForm.comps.filter((comp) => comp.id !== request.params.compId)
                existingForm.save()
                response.status(204).end()
            })
            .catch((error) => next(error))
    })

    // PUT - update a comparable company
    server.put("/responses/:id/comps/:compId", (request, response, next) => {
        const body = request.body
        if (body === undefined) {
            return response.status(400).json({ error: "content missing" })
        }

        Form.findById(request.params.id)
            .then((existingForm) => {
                const existingComps = existingForm.comps
                existingComps.forEach((comp) => {
                    if (comp.id === request.params.compId) {
                        comp.name = body.name
                        comp.ciqId = body.ciqId
                    }
                })
                existingForm.save()
                response.json(existingForm.comps)
            })
            .catch((error) => next(error))
    })

    // GET - Download file
    server.get("/download/:id", (request, response) => {
        response.setHeader("content-type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
        const readFile = __dirname + "/public/dcf_model_blank.xlsx"
        const writeFile = __dirname + `/downloads/${request.params.id}.xlsx`

        if (fs.existsSync(writeFile)) {
            try {
                fs.unlinkSync(writeFile)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }

        Form.find({}).then((form) => {
            GenerateModel(form, readFile, writeFile, response, request)
        })
    })

    // POST - leave feedback
    server.post("/feedback/:id", (request, response, next) => {
        const body = request.body

        if (body === undefined) {
            return response.status(400).json({ error: "content missing" })
        }

        const feedback = new Feedback(body)

        feedback
            .save()
            .then((savedResponse) => {
                response.json(savedResponse)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error)
            })
    })

    // GET - View feedback
    server.get("/feedback", (request, response) => {
        Feedback.find({})
            .then((feedback) => {
                response.json(feedback)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error)
            })
    })

    // GET - get markdown files
    server.get("/coursepages/:slug", (request, response) => {
        const path = __dirname + `/content/pages/${request.params.slug}.md`
        const file = fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8")
        response.send(file)
    })

    server.get("*", (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res)
    })

    const port = process.env.PORT
    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Running at localhost:${port}`)
    })
})
```

Here are the services I am using to retrieve the webpages (I am using axios). I have stored this in a file called `FormService.js`.

```
import axios from "axios"

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"

const url = dev ? "http://localhost:3001" : ""
const formID = "60e8c2ed73b100779c3356fd"

const retrieveForm = () => {
    return axios.get(`${url}/responses/${formID}`).then((response) => response.data)
}

const updateForm = (updatedForm) => {
    return axios.put(`${url}/responses/${formID}`, updatedForm).then((response) => response.data)
}

const getCompanies = () => {
    return axios.get(`${url}/responses/${formID}/comps`).then((response) => response.data)
}

const createCompany = (companyObject) => {
    return axios.post(`${url}/responses/${formID}/comps`, companyObject).then((response) => response.data)
}

const updateCompany = (id, companyObject) => {
    return axios.put(`${url}/responses/${formID}/comps/${id}`, companyObject).then((response) => response.data)
}

const removeCompany = (id) => {
    return axios.delete(`${url}/responses/${formID}/comps/${id}`)
}

const downloadFile = () => {
    return axios({
        url: `${url}/download/${formID}`,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=dcf_model.xlsx",
            "Content-Type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        },
        responseType: "blob",
    }).then((response) => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]))
        const link = document.createElement("a")
        link.href = url
        link.setAttribute("download", "dcf_model.xlsx")
        document.body.appendChild(link)
        link.click()
    })
}

const submitFeedback = (feedback) => {
    return axios.post(`${url}/feedback/${formID}`, feedback).then((response) => response.data)
}

const getPages = (slug) => {
    return axios({
        url: `${url}/coursepages/${slug}`,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "text/markdown" },
    }).then((response) => response.data)
}

const exportedServices = {
    retrieveForm,
    updateForm,
    getCompanies,
    createCompany,
    updateCompany,
    removeCompany,
    downloadFile,
    submitFeedback,
    getPages,
}

export default exportedServices
```

Finally, here is my `next.config.js`.

```
const path = require("path")

module.exports = {
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.md$/,
            use: "raw-loader",
        })
        config.resolve.alias = {
            ...config.resolve.alias,
            "@Elements": path.resolve(__dirname, "components/elements"),
            "@Modules": path.resolve(__dirname, "components/modules"),
            "@Sections": path.resolve(__dirname, "components/sections"),
            "@Layouts": path.resolve(__dirname, "components/layouts"),
            "@FormOptions": path.resolve(__dirname, "data/form-options"),
            "@FormValues": path.resolve(__dirname, "data/form-values"),
            "@CourseIndex": path.resolve(__dirname, "data/course-index"),
            "~": path.resolve(__dirname),
        }
        return config
    },
    eslint: {
        ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
    },
}
```

Many thanks, and sorry again for the long post!